# IconItemRender In Flex 4.5.1 With Dynamically Called Icon

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, air

Alright, simple item render, or so I thought... I have an some data loaded into a list, one of the fields is project_Type. It's a string that either says "RESIDENTIAL" or "COMMERCIAL". And based on that string, I just want to display a little house, or a little office building as the icon. So, I cobbled together my itemrender as follows:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:IconItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                    labelField="dateAdded" 
                    messageField="builder_Name" 
                    iconFunction="myiconfunction"
                    iconWidth="48" iconHeight="48"
                    decorator="@Embed('assets/Right-48x48.png')" >

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

    //  iconFunction="myiconfunction"
    //  iconWidth="32" iconHeight="32" -->

            private function myiconfunction(data:Object):String{

                var type:String; 

                var projectType:String = (data != null) ? data.project_Type : "QUESTION";

                if (projectType == "RESIDENTIAL") { 
                    type = "assets/House-48x48.png";
                } 
                else if (projectType == "COMMERCIAL") { 
                    type = "assets/Commercial-48x48.png";
                } 

                else if (projectType == "QUESTION") {
                    type = "assets/Question-48x48.png";
                }

                return type;

            }  

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

</s:IconItemRenderer>
```

So, pretty straight forward there... But know custom icon.... No errors either though. What am I doing wrong guys?

***Update***

So, I changed the item renderer to the following, and still no icon... I've double checked the data and RESIDENTIAL and COMMERCIAL are both being passed...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:IconItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                    labelField="dateAdded" 
                    messageField="builder_Name" 
                    iconFunction="myiconfunction"
                    iconWidth="48" iconHeight="48"
                    decorator="@Embed('assets/Right-48x48.png')" >

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            [Embed(source="assets/House-48x48.png")]
            public var residentialClass:Class;

            [Embed(source="assets/Commercial-48x48.png")]
            public var commercialClass:Class;

            [Embed(source="assets/Question-48x48.png")]
            public var questionClass:Class;

            private function myiconfunction(data:Object):Object
            {

            var projectType:String = (data != null) ? data.project_Type : "QUESTION";

            if (projectType == "RESIDENTIAL") { 
                return residentialClass;
            } 
            else if (projectType == "COMMERCIAL") { 
                return commercialClass;
            } 

            return questionClass;

            }  

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

</s:IconItemRenderer>
```

But alas, nothing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These Mods usually work for me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:IconItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                labelField="dateAdded" 
                messageField="builder_Name" 
                iconFunction="myiconfunction"
                iconWidth="48" iconHeight="48"
                decorator="@Embed('assets/Right-48x48.png')" >

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[


        private function myiconfunction(data:Object):String
        {
          var s:String = data.project_Type; //capture data for case match

          switch (s.toUpperCase()) {
                 case "RESIDENTIAL":
                      return 'assets/House-48x48.png';
                      break;
                 case "COMMERCIAL":
                      return 'assets/Commercial-48x48.png';
                      break;
                 default:
                      return 'assets/Question-48x48.png';
                      break;
            }
       }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>

</s:IconItemRenderer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your icon is ever getting called?  Are you sure the path to the icon is correct?  Are you sure the icon assets are being embedded in your compiled app?

Instead of returning the path to the object from your function, I'd probably return a class object, not a string value.  In half psuedo-code, something like this, which would be inside the renderer:

```
<fx:Script>
[Embed(source="assets/House-48x48.png")]
public resientialClass : Class;

[Embed(source="assets/Commercial-48x48.png")]
public commercialClass : Class;

[Embed(source="assets/Question-48x48.png")]
public questionClass : Class;

            private function myiconfunction(data:Object):Object

                var type:String; 

                var projectType:String = (data != null) ? data.project_Type : "QUESTION";

                if (projectType == "RESIDENTIAL") { 
                    return residentialClass;
                } 
                else if (projectType == "COMMERCIAL") { 
                    return commercialClass;
                } 

                    return questionClass;

            }  

</fx:Script>
```

Specify the renderer function the same way you do in your original code.

Comment: Wait, so I shouldn't put the render function inside the renderer? What's the usual technique for doing this?

Comment: I describe the usual technique for doing this in this post.  I've never seen the renderer function put inside the renderer before.  Maybe the list passes it the function into the renderer instance, though.  You'd have to step through the code to be sure.

Comment: Oh, lol I see now, the code you posted above does not go inside the item renderer.

Comment: Also what syntax do you use to call the icon function fot the list? I used: 

'code'
<s:List id="dataGrid" includeIn="Start" left="10" right="10" top="20" bottom="20"
   alternatingItemColors="[#FFFFFF, #C8DEFF]"
   creationComplete="projectListMain_creationCompleteHandler(event)"
   doubleClick="currentState='Detail_Project';" doubleClickEnabled="true"
   downColor="#A0B2CC" interactionMode="touch" iconFunction="myiconfunction">
'code'

But I get the cannot resolve attribute iconFunction. I've also tried iconRendererFunction, and icon...

Comment: @JasonWoodcock Apparently I am very confused and my answer is completely wrong.  The iconRendererFunction does not exist on the List class.  That is why you're getting the error.  Putting that info in a customRenderer is probably the way to go then.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: I gave it a try, and still no luck... I updated my original post to reflect the new rendering code...

Comment: Can you provide a runnable sample I can "copy and paste" into my editor and run?  Include a "hard coded" dataProvider.

Answer (score 0):

Extend the IconItemRenderer class

```
package {
import spark.components.IconItemRenderer;   
 public class CustomIconListItemRenderer extends IconItemRenderer
{   
[Embed(source="assets/House-48x48.png")]
public resientialClass : Class;

[Embed(source="assets/Commercial-48x48.png")]
public commercialClass : Class;

[Embed(source="assets/Question-48x48.png")]
public questionClass : Class;

public function CustomIconListItemRenderer()
    {
        super();
        iconFunction      = iconFunc;
             }
 private function iconFunc(data:Object):Object

            var type:String; 

            var projectType:String = (data != null) ? data.project_Type : "QUESTION";

            if (projectType == "RESIDENTIAL") { 
                return residentialClass;
            } 
            else if (projectType == "COMMERCIAL") { 
                return commercialClass;
            } 

                return questionClass;

        }  
}
}
```

So then in your list you can assign it as        itemRenderer="renderers.CustomIconListItemRenderer"